# How can I make 2D fog like in Graveyard Keeper?

Tags: unity, 2d

I really like Graveyard Keeper's fog effect but I can't work out how to make it.

It's 2D, and made in Unity. The characters all seem to be 'under' the fog, but the tops of tall trees and buildings poke out. It looks like this:

[image: Screenshot of fog in Graveyard Keeper]

The developer has given a bit of information about how it's made on Gamasutra:

http://www.gamasutra.com/blogs/SvyatoslavCherkasov/20181023/329151/Graveyard_Keeper_How_the_graphics_effects_are_made.php

> "As you see, the tops of houses and trees are seen from the fog. In fact, this effect is really easy to make. The fog consists of a great deal of horizontal clouds spread across all the picture. As a result the upper part of all the sprites is covered with a fewer amount of fog sprites:"

[image]

I used the information from this article, and [one of the developer's tweets that included this picture](https://twitter.com/LazyBearGames/status/951811970310856704):

[image]

I attempted to recreate it this fog effect. When the character moves up or down the screen, it flickers as it crosses each fog sprite:

[image: Animated gif showing character moving through fog]

What have I missed?

All of the sprites are on the default sorting layer and have sorting order 0.

The project, in Graphics Settings -> Camera Settings has the custom axis and sort axis (0,1,0). The tree and character are on the same z position, and the fog is spread out over several z positions:

[image: Oblique view of fog setup]

Comment: I wonder, perhaps sprites with elevation such as trees and buildings are rendered to a buffer that represents a mask. Simply then render the sprite in grey values along the y coordinate of the uv. Then use that mask to cut out the fog. Or perhaps they already have a mask of their own that is used in the fog.
btw there only seems to be one layer in the source you're using? Are you also sure it "flickers" because your fog has transparent spots?

Comment: "The tree and character are on the same z position" - initially? Or at all times? In the Graveyard Keeper effect, the character moves back and forth in the Z to move in front of & behind the clouds in smooth, continuous increments (which lets something like a soft particle shader do its work), rather than solely through discrete sort order changes. Does yours also move on the Z, or only on X and Y?

Comment: Unity2D doesn't allow for z movement does it? It's the rendering order

Comment: Did you try? Unity is still a 3D engine, even when you're using primarily 2D features within it. The Graveyard keeper diagram seems to emphasize z positioning as key to the effect, so I'd say it's worth a shot.

Comment: @DMGregory I think that's probably it - my character only moves on the X and Y axes. My reasoning was based on this gif: https://twitter.com/LazyBearGames/status/969550258236686337 - all of the trees/characters etc. look like they're on the same layer. Trees at different Y positions would need to also be at different Z positions, so perhaps that's an old version of their scene and they changed it when they added the fog.. what do you think?

Comment: By "same layer" I actually meant Z position.

Comment: Freeze-frame that animation when it's viewed side-on and you can see the arrangement of the sprites isn't flat but stepped, with objects higher on the screen sitting slightly further back.